# BeautifulSoup showing wrong results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to scrape different websites but for some of them it outputs a cloudflare url .
As the code below, I want the href values of the anchor tags for every tags that have a value(which is the href/a url.) and print each one of them in new lines.
For example in this code:

`<a href="https://www.google.com">some text</a>`

its should return the **https://www.google.com** in output which for some websites it doesn't work at all or return the output that I mentioned  below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

page = requests.get("https://www.swappa.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a", href=True)

for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

and vs code output this:

```
https://www.cloudflare.com/?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=j
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ScottHunter its not showing all the links that are present in the website

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster I  just edited my problem.

Comment: Did you take even the first debugging step of printing out `page.content` to see what you're getting?  You're getting back a billboard page that says it can't serve you because your browser doesn't do Javascript and cookies.  You'll need to use Selenium.  Note that you absolutely cannot treat all web sites identically.  Every one is different.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a problem of the beautiful soup but yeah this site first detects your IP and many data like which kinds of browser you are using etc and then forward it to the main site. this is a new type of blocking the web scrapping.